# Why return on function make a SIGBART signal?

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, error-handling, xcode4

I am novice on objective c.
I don't understand why my function doesn't work, it make an error SIGBART on the return of the function.

```
+ (NSArray*) jsonToArray:(NSString*)jsonString
{
    id mappedObj = nil;
    RKObjectMappingProvider* mapProv = [[RKObjectMappingProvider alloc] init];

    RKObjectMapping* answerMapping = [SMAnswersWrapper entityMappingForSerializer];
    answerMapping.objectClass = [NSMutableDictionary class];

    [mapProv setSerializationMapping:answerMapping forClass:[SMAnswersWrapper class]];
    RKObjectMapping *proofsEntityMapping = [SMEntityArrayWrapper entityMappingWithContentMapping:answerMapping];

    [mapProv setMapping:proofsEntityMapping forKeyPath:@""];

    if (jsonString)
    {
        id obj = [jsonString objectFromJSONString];
        if (obj)
        {
            RKObjectMapper* mapper = [[RKObjectMapper alloc] initWithObject:obj mappingProvider:mapProv];

            RKObjectMappingResult* res = [mapper performMapping];
            mappedObj = [res asCollection];

            [mapper release];
        }
    }
    [mapProv release];
    return [[[mappedObj content] retain] autorelease];
}
```

The error location is at this line :

> `return [[[mappedObj content] retain] autorelease];`

Thank you.

**EDIT**

I find my error, I can't access to content at `[[[mappedObj content] retain] autorelease];` i had to cast mappedObj.

Comment: check the Main file and check if `UIApplicationMain` is ok or not. else put break points on the code and check for the error location.

Comment: Also in    `[mapProv setMapping:proofsEntityMapping forKeyPath:@""];
` you need to provide a proper key path "Key" value.

Comment: I would also really suggest you move to `ARC`

Comment: The UiapplicationMain is Ok and the `[mapProv setMapping:proofsEntityMapping forKeyPath:@""];` it works because i check the data of serialization and it's good the only problem it's when i return the array, i've put break points, the error location is at  `return [[[mappedObj content] retain] autorelease];` 
Thank you

Comment: sorry rckoenes i don't understant what do you mean with 'move to `ARC`' ?
**EDIT**
Okay i search on google and i understand what do you mean i'am going to try move to ARC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find my error, I can't access to content at `[[[mappedObj content] retain] autorelease];` i had to cast mappedObj.

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
+ (NSArray*) jsonToArray:(NSString*)jsonString
{
    id mappedObj = nil;
    RKObjectMappingProvider* mapProv = [[RKObjectMappingProvider alloc] init];

    RKObjectMapping* answerMapping = [SMAnswersWrapper entityMappingForSerializer];
    answerMapping.objectClass = [NSMutableDictionary class];

    [mapProv setSerializationMapping:answerMapping forClass:[SMAnswersWrapper class]];
    RKObjectMapping *proofsEntityMapping = [SMEntityArrayWrapper entityMappingWithContentMapping:answerMapping];

    [mapProv setMapping:proofsEntityMapping forKeyPath:@""];

    if (jsonString)
    {
        id obj = [jsonString objectFromJSONString];
        if (obj)
        {
            RKObjectMapper* mapper = [[RKObjectMapper alloc] initWithObject:obj mappingProvider:mapProv];

            RKObjectMappingResult* res = [mapper performMapping];
            mappedObj = [res asCollection];

            [mapper release];
        }
    }
    [mapProv release];
    if (mappedObj)
    {
        return [[[mappedObj content] retain] autorelease];
    }
    return [NSArray array];

}
```

In your code if `jsonString` or `obj` will be nil, mappedObj will not be initialized. This case may cause crash while accessing `[mappedObj content]`.

Try this, this will help you.....

Comment: Thank you, i've already found the error, i can't access to content without cast my object.